# Select from table where another value doesn't exist in any of the joined tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select

I am trying to retrieve the IDs from a table in Oracle only IF another column value doesn't exist in any of the joined tables. Let me give you an example:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzFuG.png)

As you can see in the sketch, Table A is joined to tables B via the ID. I would like to get the IDs from Table A only if all statuses in any joined Table B DO NOT contain the value 2.

Here is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN TABLE B
ON A.ID = B.REF_ID
WHERE B.STATUS NOT IN (2)
```

Unfortunately, I still get all IDs (which makes sense) and am not able to come up with a method to retrieve only the IDs without a certain value in the Status column of a joined table. Hence, I would only like to get ID 1, since all joined tables do not contain the value 2 in their Status.

Many thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE A LEFT JOIN
     TABLE B
     ON A.ID = B.REF_ID 
GROUP BY A.ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN B.STATUS IN (2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Or, simply use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT A.ID
FROM TABLE A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM B
                  WHERE A.ID = B.REF_ID AND B.STATUS IN (2)
                 );
```